# ES6 for-of loop in map key value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use for-of loop for my map which look something like this

```
var map = new Object();
map["myKey1"] = "myVal";
map["myKey2"] = "myVal";

for (let [key, value] of map) {
  console.log(key + ' is ' + value);
}
```

but I am getting **TypeError: map[Symbol.iterator] is not a function**

Please suggest solution for this.